# How to add values in second column if corresponding values in first column are same in bash?

Tags: bash

I need to add values in 2nd column if values are same in 1st column:

```
#sorted-file.txt
a 1
a 5
a 4
b 3
b 7
b 10
#so on ..

#out.txt
a 10
b 20
#so on ..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk '{sums[$1]+=$2} END{for (i in sums) print i, sums[i]}' file
a 10
b 20
```

Above solution might change the order of column as per the internal hashing of associative arrays. To maintain the original order use:

```
awk '!($1 in sums){ord[++n]=$1} {sums[$1]+=$2} 
     END{for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print ord[i], sums[ord[i]]}' file
a 10
b 20
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks